# How can I get a boolean out of a reiteration

Tags: c

I made this binary search using reiteration, however, when I get the answer (boolean), I seem to stumble in my way out of the reiteration and cant get the correct answer out of the function. 
Can anybody help? Please comment on the code.

```
// binary search
bool 
search(int value, int array[], int n)
{

    // the array has more than 1 item
    if (n > 1)
    {
        int m = (n/2);

        // compares the middle point to the value
        if (value == array [m])
            return true;

        // if the value given is lower than the middle point of the array
        if (value < array [m])
        {
            int *new_array = malloc (m * sizeof(int));

            // creating a new array with the lower half of the original one
            memcpy(new_array, array, m * sizeof(int));

            // recalling the function
            search (value, new_array, m);
        }


        // if the value given is greater than the middle point of the array
        else
        {
            int *new_array = malloc (m * sizeof(int));

            // creating a new array with the upper half of the original one
            memcpy(new_array, array + (m + 1), (m  * sizeof(int)));

            // recalling the function
            search (value, new_array, m);
        }
    }

    else if (n==1)
    {

        // comparing the one item array with the value
        if (array[0] == value)
            return true;

        else
            return false;

    }

    if (true)
        return true;

    else 
        return false;



}
```

Comment: why did you write that `if (true) return true; else return false;`? Also, the `malloc()` and `memcpy()`s are superfluous and you're badly leaking memory.

Comment: Note that tou are copying half of the array each iteration. It effectively makes the algorithm VERY inefficient. Your algorithm runs in `O(n)`, and not `O(logN)` (It does not answer the question, but it is important issue nevertheless)

Comment: Re the other comments, you should have the start and end of the part of the array that you want to be working on as parameters, instead of copying the part of the array you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value of recursive searches.

```
return search (value, new_array, m);
```

Otherwise when you call search you are just throwing away the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should `return search(...);`, and not only invoke the `search()` method - otherwise the return value is not bubbled up.

In addition, note that this algorithm is `O(n)` (linear in the size of the array) and is leaking memory and very inefficient, since you copy half of the array in each iteration. 

Actually, It probably makes the algorithm much slower then the naive linear search for an element.

A good binary search does not need to copy half of the array - it just "looks" at half of it. It can be achieved by sending `array+m` as the array (for the higher half), and only decreasing `n` is enough for the lower half.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by amint copying the array completely defeats the purpose of doing a binary search.  Second, I believe you mean recursion, not reiteration.

Things to think about:  Instead of copying the array, think about how you could achieve the same result by passing in a set of indexes to the array (like beginning and end).

As to your actual question, how to return the boolean value through the recursion.  The thing about returning values out of a recursive function is that each iteration has to pass along the value.  You can think of it like a chain of responsibility delegation.  The first call is like the head of the company.  He doesn't do all of the work, so he delegates it to his assistant but he does one piece of the work first.  Then the assistant has an assistant etc. Turtles all the way down ;)

In order to get a value back though, each person in the chain has to give it back to the person before them.  Going back to programming, this means that every time you recursively call search, you need to return that value.

Lastly, once you have those things in order you need to get your base case better defined.  I assume that's what you're trying to do with
    if (true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
However, as pointed out by H2CO3, this doesn't make much sense.  In fact, your previous if statement `if (n == 1) ...` should make sure that the code after that is never executed.